# При попытке подключения к localhost выдет ошибку "Connection refused". С чем это может быть связано или как можно проанализировать ошибку?

Tags: python, сокет

Код:

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('172.0.0.1', 1234))
```

При этом выдает ошибку 111

> Connection refused

С чем это может быть связано? Или как можно проанализировать ошибку, чтобы ее исправить?

Comment: вероятно на порту 1234 никто не слушает. или фаервол не пропускает (но это маловероятно)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В целом, правильный ответ, действительно в том, что на порту никто не слушает.

А не слушает, скорее всего, из-за того, что IP адрес неправильный - должен быть 127.0.0.1 для localhost (в отличии от 172.0.0.1 в Вашем примере)

В таких случаях, имеет смысл пробовать подключиться сторонними утилитами (такими как телнет), чтобы проверить в чём проблема - в питоне или в порту.

```
atlant@NewFarm:/$ telnet localhost 8888
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^
```

Comment: можно заметить, что в отличии от [`172.16.0.1` (rfc 1918)](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1918#section-3), `172.0.0.1` не является частным адресом и поэтому вероятно внешнему серверу принадлежит.

Answer (score -1):

На порту никто не слушает. Поэтому не к чему подключаться.

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Сейчас ничего не понятно.